# Unable to set relative line number as a default

Tags: debugging, line-numbers

I am trying to setup Emacs to have relative line numbering enabled by default via [this](https://github.com/coldnew/linum-relative) plugin.

According to the readme file

> Relative line numbering should already be enabled by default (by installing this package), following linum-on

I have included `(linum-on)` in my `.emacs` file but it doesn't work.  `M-x linum-relative-mode` works, but I have to do it every time.

My full `.emacs` file at present is below:

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (progn
      (setq initial-frame-alist
            '((tool-bar-lines . 0)
              (width . 106)
              (height . 60)))
      (setq default-frame-alist
            '((tool-bar-lines . 0)
              (width . 106)
              (height . 60))))
  (progn
    (setq initial-frame-alist '((tool-bar-lines . 0)))
    (setq default-frame-alist '((tool-bar-lines . 0)))))
(setq package-list
      '(use-package evil helm js2-mode monokai-theme linum-relative org
        powerline rainbow-delimiters projectile helm-projectile flycheck))
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives '(("melpa"        . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("MELPA stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("gnu"          . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade"    . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))
(dolist (package package-list)
  (unless (package-installed-p package) (package-install package))) 
(setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)

;; Use `display-line-number-mode` as linum-mode's backend for smooth performance
(setq linum-relative-backend 'display-line-numbers-mode)
(require 'linum-relative)
(linum-on)
(require 'helm-config)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 140)
(load-theme 'monokai t)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(require 'powerline)
(powerline-default-theme)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(linum-relative-mode)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (flycheck rainbow-delimiters powerline linum-relative doom-themes moe-theme cyberpunk-theme monokai-theme helm evil))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: On a side note, if you're on Emacs 26, you should switch to `display-line-numbers-mode`. (It is a lot more efficient than `linum-mode`). (setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative) ;; Make relative line numbers appear for all programming buffers. (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)

Comment: Rather than just dump your init file here, please consider paring it down to just the code that's essential to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Drew noted; I'll bear that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linum-on` acts on the current buffer only.
That is not what you want in an init file.

You actually want the action of `global-linum-mode` which switches on `linum-mode` in all buffers where it is appropriate.

So replace `(linum-on)` with `(global-linum-mode)`.
You can also directly use

`(linum-relative-global-mode)`

instead.